# Rails + devise sign_in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Devise throws:

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `login' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000004e42d80>):
"
```

every time I try to log in.
In this application "login" field is used as authentication key:

/config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

In session_controller.rb I used `before_filter`:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) { |u| u.permit(:login, :password) }
  end
```

And my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations', :invitations => 'users/invitations'}
```

This problem appeared after upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4.
Can someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

My bad. Found wrong parameter in devise initializer, set by my co-worker. 
Anyway i have error message:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `invitation_token' for #<User:0x0000000286c750>):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

sessions#create:

```
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    render :json => { :user_id => resource.id }, :status => :created
  end
```

UPDATE

Crap. My co-worker also changed database.yml to another DB. So this DB was not migrated to last state =. After rake db:migrate all works fine. Thanks to all.

Comment: post your views of sessions new

Comment: Rajarshi, my application works just as API.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue here is generally that devise's invitable code is generated by an second step in your devise work flow, a generator that makes a second migration:

```
$ rails g devise_invitable:install
$ rails g devise_invitable User   (where User is my Model)
$ rake db:migrate
```

What you need to check for is if both migrations are in sync (in my case I reran the user migration but NOT the invitable migration and thus my user table was incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), you should create a **login** virtual attribute in the User model.

`#Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email`
`#This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'`
`attr_accessor :login`

Also add login to attr_accessible for rails 3

```
attr_accessible :login
```

You may also need to overwrite Devise's find_for_database_authentication method in User model
(assuming it is activerecord)

```
# app/models/user.rb

    def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
    end
```

You may need to modify config/initializers/devise.rb to have

```
config.reset_password_keys = [ :login ]
config.confirmation_keys = [ :login ]
```

Comment: Table already have real attribute "login", so I don't think that virtual attribute with the same name is needed.

Comment: That's right. Could you try this `"devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user)"` -> `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in)`

Comment: In sessions_controller.rb I wrapper all params to "user"