# Rails 4 + Devise DB Sign In: NoMethodError `login' for ActionDispatch::Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm having what I believe is the same issue as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653177/rails-devise-sign-in-error). I've also seen this error with "email" instead of "login" before I configured to allow username based sign in.

I can create a user fine. The user just can't sign in. Here are some key variables from config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
config.request_keys = [ :login ]
config.http_authenticatable = [false]
```

Here is the form from controllers/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :login %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :login, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
     <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
 <% end -%>

 <div><%= f.submit "Log in" %></div>
 <% end %>
```

Here are the parameters submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"yada",
    "user"=>{"login"=>"me@example.org", 
      "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
      "remember_me"=>"0"}, 
    "commit"=>"Log in"}
```

rails 4.1, devise 3.4

Backtrace:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `login' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000000661c758>):
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:148:in`block in request_values'
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:148:in `map'
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:148:in`request_values'
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:128:in `with_authentication_hash'
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:77:in`valid_for_params_auth?'
>     devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:16:in `valid?'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:351:in`block in _run_strategies_for'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `each'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in`_run_strategies_for'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:319:in `_perform_authentication'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:127:in`authenticate!'
>     devise (3.4.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`send_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in`call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`block in halting'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`block in halting'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in`run_callbacks'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`block in instrument'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in`instrument'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
>     activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
>     actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in`block in action'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`dispatch'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in`call'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'
>     warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>     activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>     activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>     railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
>     railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
>     railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>     activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>     actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
>     railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in`call'
>     railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
>     rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
>     /home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>     /home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>     /home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please show the migration which creates "users" table and the User model?

Comment: You can checkout the model and migrations here: https://gist.github.com/ArbolEric/0599a93e36380aaed7c9

Answer (score 1):

You use a virtual attribute called `login` as the authentication key. What's missing is overriding Devise's `find_for_database_authentication`

See [here](http://bit.ly/1yV8hGn)